# Is it possible to change the name of controller in URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller

```
 emppedes
```

Its fine when i want to call this in url i see

```
localhost:3000/emppedes
```

and whole the content related to it appears.

But can i match this controller to others name in rails so that when i click in it I can get in URL like

```
localhost:3000/employees
```

without changing the controller inside but outside in url you can see that.
I mean can i code somewhere like

```
 `emppedes will display as employees in URL.`
```

Is it possible. May be my question is stupid but I want to know whether it is possible or not.
In edit i have two send two different id and in controller also for update i have to send two id.
For edit my code is like

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', { :action => "edit",:id => @emppede.id,:ad => @id},:class=>"btn btn-success" %> |
```

since i have two handle two id in controller
Also for update

```
 @id= @emppede.ad

if @emppede.save
        format.html { redirect_to :action => :index, :id => @emppede.ad }
        format.json { render json: @emppede, status: :created, location: @emppede }
```

How can i send two params :id and :ad both in rails path formate?
Since my controller is like this

```
def index
         @id = params[:id]
      @data = Emppede.where(:ad => @id)
    if @data.count > 0
      @data.each do |data|
        @ids= data.id
         end
      redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @ids, :ad => @id
     else
      redirect_to :action => :new, :id => @id
    end
  end
```

Comment: You've now changed your question to two different things. You might be better off splitting it into two questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to accomplish with the second half. We need more clarification. Why do you need two params if ad is part of an Emppede? Why are you redirecting to show with multiple IDs? Why do you redirect index to new?

Comment: one id is user id that is params[:ad] other is the params[:id] that is  id of the data.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of REST. Index should not take an ID. It's supposed to list model instances. In your case list filtered on 'ad', only one parameters needed and no redirects.

Comment: Then how can i do. You can see my controller code. There i have to send user id where it search the data of that user  @data = Emppede.where(:ad => @id). here in every data in ad field there is the id of the users. Hence in controller index it shows the related data of that user. How can i do. Can u edit my question. I am messed up

Comment: You probably want to ask another question as to what's the best way to organize your models. It doesn't seem like you modelled what you need properly.

Comment: You are right. I am new here.Can u give me the best idea how can i implement.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can just specify the controller to use for any given resource:

```
resources :employees, :controller => "emppedes"
```

Or if you prefer the Ruby 1.9 syntax:

```
resources :employees, controller: "emppedes"
```

For more details, see [Rails Guide: Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use).

Comment: it only works for index for first time , for edit, view next time it does not work. Any solution

Comment: If you declared employees to be the resource you'll want to use the employee helpers. For edit you'd use edit_employee_path(id). If you use the routing helper for another resource it will obviously not follow the employee pattern. See the example on the Rails Guide I linked.

Comment: here i have to send id and ad . How can i send two params? You can see my updated question.

Answer (score 3):

What you will want to do is pass in the :path option

resources :employees, :path => "emppedes"

This replace all your route references with /employees to /emppedes

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, Section 4.7 Translating Paths

Comment: here i have to send id and ad . How can i send two params? You can see my updated question

Comment: If I understand it correct this is meant for language translation and not necessarily mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in routes.rb for your queries

```
match '/employees/:id/:ad(.:format)' => 'emppedes#index', :via => :get, :as => :employees
resources :emppedes, :as => 'employees'
```

Comment: I added only  the URl for index action alone. I hope you are getting error in edit action. is it right?

Comment: yes you are right. But problem is it is not showing employees in URL . It is showing emppedes.

Comment: match '/employees/:id/:ad(.:format)' => 'emppedes#index', :via => :get, :as => :employees
resources :emppedes, :as => 'employees'

Comment: Yes. It is in routes.rb. My query is how you are visting the employees page from some other page. If you call '/employees/1/2' it will work. You can get '1' in params[:id] and '2' in params[:ad]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20734/discussion-between-regmiprem-and-shiva)

Answer (score 0):

try use inflections in your initialize file

```
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
     inflect.irregular 'employees', 'emppedes'
  end
```

Comment: This would be a very ugly hack which abuses the flexibility of ActiveSupport::Inflector well beyond its intended use. The doc is pretty clear on its use: "The Inflector transforms words from singular to plural, class names to table names, modularized class names to ones without, and class names to foreign keys".